# Showing Alert Message Before Saving Model in Django Admin

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates, django-admin

There are ways to show a message **after** a model has been saved in the database or if there is any error while saving. But how do I show an alert when the user clicks **save** button in Django Admin? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The only way to do that is by using Javascript or even better jQuery that Django Admin [already provides](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/javascript/) for you.

Answer (score 6):

If you explored the django admin then you can see that django uses [submit_line.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/submit_line.html) for rendering the save ( save & continue ) buttons.

There are multiple ways to do it,

1 ) If you want app wise alerts, then in your `admin.py` file include the custom js file with admin media option,

```
@admin.register(Model)
class ModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   class Media:
        js = (
            'js/myscript.js',  # project's static folder ( /static/js/myscript.js )
        )
```

In your `myscript.js` write,

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
(function ($) {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        var c = confirm("continue submitting ?");
        return c;
    });


})(django.jQuery);
```

});
2 ) If you want alerts for all the forms in admin just inherit [submit_line.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/submit_line.html) in `templates/admin/submit_line.html` directory and simply write,

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form').submit(function() {
            var c = confirm("continue submitting ?");
            return c;
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: can you link your answer with some sources?

Comment: Link to media form https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/media/#form-asset-paths

Comment: Is there a way to add css to the confirm?

Answer (score 5):

> But how do I show an alert when the user clicks save button in Django
>   Admin? Is there a way to do that?

It's called [validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/). Django best practice is making validation on the server and this way described [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin).

You need to do following steps:

1. Set `form` in you admin model.
2. Define `clean_name` method in your new form, where `name` is a name of the field which you want to check. You can also overwrite whole [clean](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other).
3. If there's a error then raise a `ValidationError` to send message to the user. If you raise exception in `clean_name` method `name` field will be highlighted in an interface.

---

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin


class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyArticleAdminForm


class MyArticleAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean_name(self):
        if some_condition:
            raise ValidationError("Message which you want to show to the user")
        return self.cleaned_data["name"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show an alert message by clicking on `SAVE(Save)` button when there is some error in Django Admin.

For example, there is `Person` model as shown below:

```py
# "app1/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

#### <`Add` and `Change` pages>

First, I explain how to show an alert message by clicking on `SAVE` button on `Add` and `Change` pages when there is some error in Django Admin.

So, there is `Person` admin as shown below:

```py
# "app1/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Then, create `additional.js` in `core/static/core/admin/app1/js/` and copy [submit_line.html](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#templates-which-may-be-overridden-per-app-or-model) from `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/submit_line.html` in your virtual environment to `templates/admin/app1/person/` as shown below. *You can see the original [submit_line.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/submit_line.html):

```
Django Project
 |-core
 |  |-settings.py
 |  └-static
 |     └-core
 |        └-admin
 |           └-app1
 |              └-js
 |                 └-additional.js # Here
 |-app1
 |  |-models.py
 |  └-admin.py
 |-app2
 └-templates
    └-admin
       └-app1
          └-person
             └-submit_line.html # Here
```

Then in `additional.js`, define `checkIfEmpty()` which shows an alert message if `first_name` or `last_name` is empty as shown below:

```js
// "core/static/core/admin/app1/js/additional.js"

function checkIfEmpty() {
    let firstName = document.querySelector(
        'form input[name="first_name"]'
    ).value;
    let lastName = document.querySelector(
        'form input[name="last_name"]'
    ).value;
    if (firstName == "" || lastName == "") {
        alert("Fill all fields!!")
        return false
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then, add `onclick="return checkIfEmpty();"` to `<input ... name="_save">` in `submit_line.html` as shown below:

```
# "templates/admin/app1/person/submit_line.html"

# ...

{% block submit-row %}
{% if show_save %}
<input 
  type="submit" 
  value="{% translate 'Save' %}" 
  class="default" 
  name="_save" 
  onclick="return checkIfEmpty();" # Here
>
{% endif %}
{% if show_delete_link and original %}

# ...
```

Then, set `"core/admin/app1/js/additional.js"` to `js` in [Media class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/media/#extend) as shown below:

```py
# "app1/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media: # Here
        js = ("core/admin/app1/js/additional.js",)
```

Then, an alert message is shown by clicking on `SAVE` button because `First name:` is empty on `Add` page and `Last name:` is empty on `Change` page as shown below. *With this example, the alert message is shown only on **Person** `Add` and `Change` pages but not on other admin `Add` and `Change` pages:

[image]

[image]

And, if you want to show the alert message only in `Add` page, add `{% if not change %}...{% endif %}` in `submit_line.html` as shown below:

```
# "templates/admin/app1/person/submit_line.html"

# ...

{% block submit-row %}
{% if show_save %}
<input 
  type="submit" 
  value="{% translate 'Save' %}" 
  class="default" 
  name="_save" 
  {% if not change %}onclick="return checkIfEmpty();"{% endif %} # Here
>
{% endif %}
{% if show_delete_link and original %}

# ...
```

And, if you want to show the alert message only in `Change` page, add `{% if change %}...{% endif %}` in `submit_line.html` as shown below:

```
# "templates/admin/app1/person/submit_line.html"

# ...

{% block submit-row %}
{% if show_save %}
<input 
  type="submit" 
  value="{% translate 'Save' %}" 
  class="default" 
  name="_save" 
  {% if change %}onclick="return checkIfEmpty();"{% endif %} # Here
>
{% endif %}
{% if show_delete_link and original %}

#...
```

And, you can directly define `checkIfEmpty()` in `submit_line.html` as shown below without defining `checkIfEmpty()` in `additional.js` and setting it to `js` in [Media class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/media/#extend):

```
# "templates/admin/app1/person/submit_line.html"

# ...

{% block submit-row %}
{% if show_save %}
<input 
  type="submit" 
  value="{% translate 'Save' %}" 
  class="default" 
  name="_save" 
  onclick="return checkIfEmpty();" # Here
>
{% endif %}
{% if show_delete_link and original %}

# ...

<script>
function checkIfEmpty() {
    let firstName = document.querySelector(
        'form input[name="first_name"]'
    ).value;
    let lastName = document.querySelector(
        'form input[name="last_name"]'
    ).value;
    if (firstName == "" || lastName == "") {
        alert("Fill all fields!!")
        return false
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

#### <`Change List` page>

Next, I explain how to show an alert message by clicking on `Save` button on `Change List` page when there is some error in Django Admin.

So, there is `Person` admin as shown below:

```py
# "app1/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name')
    list_editable = ('first_name', 'last_name')
    list_display_links = None
    ordering = ('id',)
```

Then, create `additional.js` in `core/static/core/admin/app1/js/` and copy [pagination.html](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/admin/#templates-which-may-be-overridden-per-app-or-model) from `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/pagination.html` in your virtual environment to `templates/admin/app1/person/` as shown below. *You can see the original [pagination.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/pagination.html):

```
Django Project
 |-core
 |  |-settings.py
 |  └-static
 |     └-core
 |        └-admin
 |           └-app1
 |              └-js
 |                 └-additional.js # Here
 |-app1
 |  |-models.py
 |  └-admin.py
 |-app2
 └-templates
    └-admin
       └-app1
          └-person
             └-pagination.html # Here
```

Then in `additional.js`, define `checkIfEmpty()` which shows an alert message if `first_name` or `last_name` is empty as shown below:

```js
// "core/static/core/admin/app1/js/additional.js"

function checkIfEmpty() {
    let firstNames = document.querySelectorAll(
        'form#changelist-form input[name$="first_name"]'
    );
    let lastNames = document.querySelectorAll(
        'form#changelist-form input[name$="last_name"]'
    );
    for (let i = 0; i < firstNames.length; i++) {
        if (firstNames[i].value == "" || lastNames[i].value == "") {
            alert("Fill all fields!!");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then, add `onclick="return checkIfEmpty();"` to `<input ... value="{% translate 'Save' %}">` in `pagination.html` as shown below:

```
# "templates/admin/app1/person/pagination.html"

# ...

{% if cl.formset and cl.result_count %}
<input 
  type="submit" 
  name="_save" 
  class="default" 
  value="{% translate 'Save' %}"
  onclick="return checkIfEmpty();" # Here
>
{% endif %}
</p>
```

Then, set `"core/admin/app1/js/additional.js"` to `js` in [Media class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/media/#extend) as shown below:

```py
# "app1/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name')
    list_editable = ('first_name', 'last_name')
    list_display_links = None
    ordering = ('id',)

    class Media: # Here
        js = ("core/admin/app1/js/additional.js",)
```

Then, an alert message is shown by clicking on `Save` button because `FIRST NAME` field is empty as shown below. *With this example, the alert message is shown only on **Person** `Change List` page but not on other admin `Change List` pages:

[image]

And, you can directly define `checkIfEmpty()` in `pagination.html` as shown below without defining `checkIfEmpty()` in `additional.js` and setting it to `js` in [Media class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/media/#extend):

```
# "templates/admin/app1/person/pagination.html"

# ...

{% if cl.formset and cl.result_count %}
<input 
  type="submit" 
  name="_save" 
  class="default" 
  value="{% translate 'Save' %}"
  onclick="return checkIfEmpty();" # Here
>
{% endif %}
</p>

<script>
function checkIfEmpty() {
    let firstNames = document.querySelectorAll(
        'form#changelist-form input[name$="first_name"]'
    );
    let lastNames = document.querySelectorAll(
        'form#changelist-form input[name$="last_name"]'
    );
    for (let i = 0; i < firstNames.length; i++) {
        if (firstNames[i].value == "" || lastNames[i].value == "") {
            alert("Fill all fields!!");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```