# Django: How to check that an inline action has been executed?

Tags: django

I have three actions and it just so happens that I have to fix this code so that the application makes sure or at least warns the user (this is still being defined) that they have skipped a step.

In my admin.py I have three inline actions:

```
actions = [clean_data, rel_from_db, send_production]
```

They just run actions related to a database in this manner:

```
def send_production(modeladmin, request, queryset):
for qs in queryset:
    qs.clean_data()
```

How can I instead stop the execution (before the loop) to make sure the performed the two previous steps? Could I just save a variable in admin.py that keeps the state. I read the ValidationError indicated [in this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45601277/showing-alert-message-before-saving-model-in-django-admin) but I'm confused because I wanna validate inline actions (functions) and not exactly a form field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All actions are completely separate requests, theoretically separated by any amount of time. This is a consequence of a stateless model of a web server.
You will need to keep track of the state in the Model(s) and validate based on its state. For example:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    NEW = 'new'
    CLEANED = 'cleaned'
    SEND = 'send' # etc, add more states if needed

    state = models.CharField(choices=((NEW, NEW), (CLEANED, CLEANED), (SEND, SEND)), max_length=50, default=NEW)

def send_production(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    if queryset.exclude(state=MyModel.CLEANED).exists():
        self.message_user(request, 'Some of the selected objects are not cleaned yet', messages.ERROR)
        return

    for qs in queryset:
        qs.send_to_production()  # changes .state to MyModel.SEND
```